# How to properly make a table association using hasOne, belongsTo using Sequelize and express js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am working on expre6ssjs with sequelize version 6.
I have User and Message and I need to make one to many relationship between them.

here is what I have so far

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from "sequelize";

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  'messagenger',
  'mysql',
  'password',
  {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'
  }
);

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database: ', error);
});

const User = sequelize.define("users", {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
});

const Message = sequelize.define("messages", {
  text: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
});

sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {

  // User.hasMany(Message, {
  //   foreignKey: "user_id",
  //   as: "messages"
  // });
  // Message.belongsTo(User, {
  //   foreignKey: "user_id",
  //   as: "users"
  // });

  // Message.belongsTo(User, {
  //   foreignKey: "userId",
  //   as: "user"
  // })

  Message.belongsTo(User);
  User.hasMany(Message);

}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Unable to create table : ', error);
});
```

this is my messages table.

```
mysql> describe messages;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| text      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| createdAt | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have tried a couple of versions as you can see in the comments. but nothing worked.
https://sebhastian.com/sequelize-hasone/
I was following this tutorial and this does not look complicated at all.

By the way, I have been searching for the answer for a while now. And I know people also use a different approach such as referenced in the table definition.
But my goal is to use `hasMany, belongsTo`, these methods as they are very explicit.

Any advice will help me a lot.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define all models and associations **BEFORE** calling `sync` in order to Sequelize to know all about what tables and foreign key fields and foreign key constraints it needs to create.

```js
const User = sequelize.define("users", {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
});

const Message = sequelize.define("messages", {
  text: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
});

Message.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(Message);

sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
  console.info('Model synchronization completed');
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Unable to create table : ', error);
});
```

Comment: Hi Anatoly, 
Thank you very much for helping !!!
I was able to resolve the issue.